# Probability of some dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

**Question**

A fair six-sided die is rolled $12$ times. Find the probability that each of the six possible outcomes ($1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ and $6$) come up at least once.

**My working**

Let $X_n$ be the random variable denoting the number of times $n$ appears, out of $12$ rolls. For example, $X_1$ will be the random variable denoting the number of times $1$ appears, out of $12$ rolls.

Then, $$X_n \sim B(12, \frac 1 6)$$ and the required probability is

\begin{align}
P(X_1 \geq 1)P(X_2 \geq 1)P(X_3 \geq 1)P(X_4 \geq 1)P(X_5 \geq 1)P(X_6 \geq 1) & = [P(X \geq 1)]^6
\\[5 mm] & =
[1 - P(X = 0)]^6
\\[5 mm] & =
\left[1 - \left(\frac 5 6\right)^{12}\right]^6
\\[5 mm] & \approx
0.490
\end{align}

**Answer**

The solution by my professor gives the required probability as $$1 - 
\left[\binom 6 1 \left(\frac 5 6\right)^{12} - \binom 6 2 \left(\frac 4 6\right)^{12} + \binom 6 3 \left(\frac 3 6\right)^{12} - \binom 6 4 \left(\frac 2 6\right)^{12} + \binom 6 5 \left(\frac 1 6\right)^{12}\right] \approx 0.438.$$

---

The solution does come with an explanation, but I am very confused by it, so I am hoping to find more intuitive suggestions on why my working is wrong as well as how to go about approaching the problem.

Comment: The solution of your professor is correct. The events in question are not independent and you cannot just multiply the probabilities. You need to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Instead of looking for an alternate solution, you should try and understand the solution provided by your professor. If you are in this field, you will have to sooner or later learn P.I.E. It may not be intuitive today but it will become intuitive soon once you understand.

Comment: Do you understand what is wrong with your solution? The point that everyone has made is that events are not independent. Is it clear why?

Comment: @MathLover I know what PIE is about and I have also realised why the events are not independent, but I still struggle to see how to apply the PIE to this problem.

Comment: btw for the P.I.E solution that you have posted, first think in terms of cases where at least one of the numbers is missing. Start with where one of the numbers is missing, say $1$. Then find number of possibile outcomes as we only have $5$ numbers appearing. That is $5^{12}$. But it will also include cases where one of the five number is missing and those have been overcounted. So comes the next term where two of the numbers are missing and so on...

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I see it now. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that the random variables $X_i$'s are independent but this is not the case.

Let $A_i$ be the event that $i$ occur, we want to compute $$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^6 A_i\right)=1-P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i^c\right)$$

We then compute $P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i^c\right)$ by inclusion-exclusion principle.

Notice that we have

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c\right)=\left( \frac{6-m}{6}\right)^{12}$$

By symmetry:

$$P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i^c\right)=\sum_{m=1}^6 (-1)^{m+1}\binom{6}{m}P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the help! I know what PIE is about, but in your answer, how do we derive $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c\right)=\left( \frac{6-m}{6}\right)^{12}$? I am trying to understand the relevance of this equation in solving the problem.

Comment: $P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c \right)$ is the probability that in the $12$ tosses, we don't see any occurence of $1, \ldots, m$. For example if $m=3$, then we don't see $1,2,3$. $m$ takes values from $1$ to $6$.

Comment: @EthanMark Let $A_i$ denote the event that outcome $i$ comes up at least once (out of the 12 rolls). Then $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c\right)$ is the probability that outcomes $1,2,\dots, m$ does not come up out of the 12 rolls. Since each roll is independent of each other, the probability that outcomes $1,2,\dots, m$ does not come up at any given roll is $\frac{6-m}{6}$. Putting these together, we have $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_i^c\right)=\left( \frac{6-m}{6}\right)^{12}$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I guess there might be a slight typo in the last line. Should there actually be  no $m$ in the formula, i.e. $P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^6 A_i^c\right)=\sum_{i=1}^6 (-1)^{i+1}\binom{6}{i}P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^i A_j^c\right)$?

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I understand that now, but now I have trouble understand your very last equation. How do you know that the binominal coefficient must be there? For example, the closed form of PIE from Wikipedia does not have the binomial coefficient. Is there an intuitive understanding for this?

Comment: it's because of symmetry, for example, out of the $6$ events, we want to consider all the pairs, by symetry, we have $\binom62$ pairs and each pair have the same probability. Similarly, for every triplets and so on.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6$ as you defined are NOT independent random variables, due to the constraint that
$$\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i = 12.$$
Therefore, the probability that each of the six possible outcomes (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6) come up at least once, i.e. $P(X_1 \geq 1, X_2 \geq 1, X_3 \geq 1, X_4 \geq 1, X_5 \geq 1, X_6 \geq 1)$, cannot be factorized as the product of $P(X_i \geq 1), i = 1,\dots,6$.